# llvm - Access And Call Function Pointer In A Global Array Without Horrible Pointer Hacking

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-construction, llvm, function-pointers

I am having quite some trouble programmatically accessing a function pointer in a global array programmatically. I have a global array of function pointers, my "lookup table" which I basically I am using for "overloads". Every time I try to GetElementPointer (GEP)/`getelementptr` an element in this array with the desired type, I get a runtime assertion:

```
warp_compiler: /root/.conan/data/llvm-core/13.0.0/_/_/package    /6efbb14f313e71b5e1dbf77c1c011f47614b7c7c/include/llvm/IR/
Instructions.h:960: static llvm::GetElementPtrInst* llvm::GetElementPtrInst::Create(
llvm::Type*, llvm::Value*, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Value*>, const llvm::Twine&, llvm::Instruction*): 
Assertion `cast<PointerType>(Ptr->getType()->getScalarType()) ->isOpaqueOrPointeeTypeMatches(PointeeType)' 
failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Now the type of the array when compiled is `[3 x i32 (i32)*]` by default it tries to do a a GEP on `[3 x i32 (i32)*]*` with element type `[3 x i32 (i32)*]` which does not work.

If I manaually edit the code to be:

```
%option_address = getelementptr i32 (i32)*, [3 x i32 (i32)*]* @my_function_1_table, i32 %7
```

Or too:

```
%option_address = getelementptr i32 (i32)*, [3 x i32 (i32)*] @my_function_1_table, i32 %7
```

it works just dandy, the ladder is really what I am looking to do. But I cant seem to do it probrammatically because of this exception.

I have tried casting the array to `i32 (i32)*` with:

```
    auto first_element = context->builder.CreatePointerBitCastOrAddrSpaceCast(
            (llvm::Value*) lookup_table_global, 
            (llvm::Type*) function->getType(), 
            "cast"
        );
```

Then trying to access the elements with something like:

```
auto element = context->builder.CreateGEP(
         (llvm::Type*) function->getType(), 
         first_element,                                             
         index_array,
         "option_address"
     );
```

But I get that exception again, and it does work if I type it manually into the IR

```
%option_address = getelementptr i32 (i32)*, i32 (i32)* @my_function_1_table, i32 %7
```

Seems like a pretty regular way to access an array, right?

But I cant seem to do it programmatically, because if the assertion, I even tried to make a work around by tryng to inherit from `GetElementPtrInst` directly and omitting the assertion, but couldn't (because its constructor is private).

Currently, my solution is to cast the array to a `i32 (i32)*` then to a `[1 x i32 (i32)*]` then do the GEP on a `[1 x i32(i32)*]*` with a `[1 x i32(i32)]`

```
%option_address = getelementptr [1 x i32 (i32)*], [1 x i32 (i32)*]* bitcast ([3 x i32 (i32)*]* @my_function_1_table to [1 x i32 (i32)*]*), i32 %7
```

This is horrible.

***Does anyone know how I can simply access the function pointers I need from a global (constant) array so they can be called?***
Also is my current solution portable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry you've run into this challenging aspect of LLVM. It definitely causes confusion.

There is an [entire webpage](https://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html) dedicated to trying to help folks understand the counter-intuitive design of this instruction. While the design is well motivated from *within* LLVM, it causes lots of folks confusion and frustration when they first encounter it.

The challenge you're hitting is because a GEP instruction in LLVM *always* operates on a pointer, and with global variables, that pointer is to the *variable*. When the global variable is an array as in your case, this is extra confusing -- GEP has to go through an extra layer of pointer before it gets to the array you're trying to index with it.

The [first section](https://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html#what-is-the-first-index-of-the-gep-instruction) of the GEP site I mentioned above specifically explains how the first index to a GEP works -- it indexes the base pointer directly.

The [second section](https://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html#why-is-the-extra-0-index-required) then specifically clarifies why *global variables* end up surprising here. The global variable, `@my_function_1_table` in your case, is a pointer to itself. You'll have to index that with a simple `i32 0` index first. *Then* you can add an additional index into the *array* that global variable points to.

So for a global variable with type `[3 x i32 (i32)*]`, if you want to extract the second element of the array, you need:

```
  %fptr = getelementptr [3 x i32 (i32)*], [3 x i32 (i32)*]* @my_function_1_table, i32 0, i32 2
```

The first `i32 0` here indexes the global itself. The *second* index of `i32 2` indexes into the array.

You can also use Clang to get example LLVM IR that can help explain how to do things. For example, here is some C++ that does something similar to what you're trying to do:

```cpp
using FPtrT = int (*)(int);

extern FPtrT function_ptrs[3];

int test(int i) {
  FPtrT fptr = function_ptrs[i];
  return (*fptr)(42);
}
```

And this turns into the following LLVM IR after some basic optimizations (`-O1`):

```
@function_ptrs = external dso_local local_unnamed_addr global [3 x i32 (i32)*], align 16

define dso_local i32 @_Z4testi(i32 %0) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
  %2 = sext i32 %0 to i64
  %3 = getelementptr inbounds [3 x i32 (i32)*], [3 x i32 (i32)*]* @function_ptrs, i64 0, i64 %2
  %4 = load i32 (i32)*, i32 (i32)** %3, align 8, !tbaa !4
  %5 = call i32 %4(i32 42)
  ret i32 %5
}

attributes #0 = { mustprogress uwtable "frame-pointer"="none" "min-legal-vector-width"="0" "no-trapping-math"="true" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+cx8,+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "tune-cpu"="generic" }
```

Here you can see `%3` is doing a dynamic (and `inbounds`, but that's orthogonal) version of this indexing.

You can play with this kind of IR generation using Compiler Explorer: https://cpp.compiler-explorer.com/z/ETa8nvTvh

Once you're using the API to create this *two* index GEP it should start working for you.

Also, just so you (or others) reading this don't get confused: the LLVM IR syntax changed here recently, so the latest versions of LLVM don't look quite the same. You can switch from Clang v13 to a more recent one to see what it looks like, for example here: https://cpp.compiler-explorer.com/z/Kc4er413G